# Adding GeoTIFF to OpenLayers 3?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, openlayers, openlayers-2, geotiff-tiff

I am a newbie in mapping services. I have some GeoTIFF files that I am trying to put on my OpenLayers 3 map. However, I am not finding a solid answer about putting a GeoTIFF on OpenLayers 3.

I searched OpenLayers 3 library, but I did not find a good amount of details on GeoTIFFs. I looked up my question online, but I found vague answers. Some people suggested that MapTiler should be used to overlay GeoTIFFs. I tried it, but it is asking me to upgrade to PRO version (I am a college student. I don't have money).

Additionally, some people suggested QGIS, MapServer and GeoServer.

I don't understand why I need them and how can they help me in rendering my GeoTIFF on my OpenLayers map?

Some pages also mentioned about WMS. Should I convert my GeoTIFF in WMS and then add it to the map?

Comment: WMS is Web map service, you can't convert image into wms.
But what you can do is install some server(as you mentioned GeoServer, QGIS...) that supports WMS and deliver geotiff image using  any of those.
What you can also do is, as it is done for offline browsing, you can emulate WMS and render geotiff image directly from your filesystem.
Check this link:
https://medspx.fr/kb/GIS/generate_osm/

Comment: I have installed GeoServer. I added my geotiff file to the stores. I can also export the file in different format such as pdf, png, tiff etc. However, I don't know how to add that layer to my openlayers map. Should I add it as a png and position it using lat and longs stored in the geoTiff file? Is there a better way to do this ? Please give me a suggestion. I am developing my openlayers map in Dreamweaver

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to display a GeoTIFF in a web browser using a client built with OpenLayers JavaScript, because the GeoTIFF itself won't render in a browser (it's not a standard image format supported by browsers).

What you can do is to set up a WMS server (for example using MapServer, GeoServer, QGIS, deegree...) that uses the GeoTIFFs as a data source, then call the WMS with OpenLayers.  The WMS will convert the GeoTIFFs into a format that can be viewed in a browser (png, jpeg, gif), and handle any reprojections that you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use QGIS QTILES OR QMETATILES to render a folder of JPG or PNG 256x256 tiles in XYZ GOOGLE OR TMS. Then add tile url to open layers